# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar un ID por Nombre al realizar una consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, sql-server, postgresql

Este seria mi problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta seria esta

```
SELECT p.`cantidad`,p.`id_bodega`,p.`id_pb`,p.`id_pedidos`,p.`precio_uni`,
p.`precio_uni`,p.`cantidad` * p.`precio_uni` AS subt,b.talla
FROM pedido_bodega AS p 
INNER JOIN bodega AS b ON b.`id_bodega` = p.`id_bodega`
```

Y el resultado que recibo seria algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer que al llamar datos de bodega, al llamar `id_pantalon` , en vez de retorne un numero de ID, me retorne el valor modelo que hay en la tabla pantalon según el ID en bodega

Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Por qué la etiqueta de Laravel?

Comment: Esa consulta esta para todas las bd? mysql-sql-postgresql, ademas tambien con laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es retornar el modelo, basta con hacer un anidamiento INNER:

```
SELECT p.`cantidad`, PT.`modelo` AS Modelo,p.`id_pb`,p.`id_pedidos`,p.`precio_uni`,
       p.`precio_uni`,p.`cantidad` * p.`precio_uni` AS subt,b.talla
FROM pedido_bodega AS p 
   INNER JOIN bodega AS b ON b.`id_bodega` = p.`id_bodega`
     INNER JOIN pantalon AS PT ON PT.`id_pantalon` = b.`id_pantalon`
```

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias realice el cambio como me dijo y funciono

Comment: @YairCedilloJaramillo Si te fue útil la respuesta y solucionó tu problema, márcala como correcta. Piensa que cuando formulas una pregunta otros usuarios emplean su tiempo en darte una solución.